# Why does this IF THEN SQL statement return an error?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I want to perform a conditional `right join` in this SQL

```
SELECT *
 FROM   post
   IF   1 = 1 THEN RIGHT JOIN faves ON faves.post_id_fk = post_id;  // <== error
END IF;
 WHERE  post_author_id
        LIKE 1
 ORDER  BY post_timestamp DESC
 LIMIT  0, 10
```

Is there a better/right way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From where does your condition originate?

1. If it comes from outside of SQL, why not determine whether or not to put the join into your query at that level:

   ```
   $qry = "SELECT * FROM post " . ($test ? " RIGHT JOIN ... " : "") . "...";
   ```
2. Otherwise, if it must be tested within SQL, I'd separate the different statements apart:

   ```
   DELIMITER ;;

   IF @test THEN
       SELECT * FROM post RIGHT JOIN ... ;
   ELSE
       SELECT * FROM post ... ;
   END IF;;

   DELIMITER ;
   ```